# In a football game, John scored at the rate of a goal every 91.3 minutes he was on the pitch. Assume that his goals occurred in a Poisson process.

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

In a football game, John scored at the rate of a $1$ goal every 91.3 minutes he was on the pitch. Assume that his goals occurred in a Poisson process.

$a)$ Write down the pdf of Poisson random variable with parameter $\mu.$

$b)$ Calculate the probability that John doesn't score during first $45-minute$ half of a game.

**My Working:**

$a)$ Let $X$ be random variable representing the number of minutes John needs to make $1$ goal then the pdf of such Poisson random variable is given by $f(x)=\frac{\mu^{x}{e^{-\mu}}}{x!}$.
Now I know this is the general form of Poisson distribution but the data in the problem of $1$ goal every $91.3$ minutes is something I can't seem to put in the the general form of above Poisson distribution. Obviously the parameter $\mu$ is the mean and is unknown to us. We are left with $x$ which represents the number of occurrences. kindly guide me how do I approach the problem and what information I am missing out.

$b)$ As for this part I think once I get the $pdf$, all I need will be to find out $1-Pr(X\leq45)$. Is my working Okay? Kindly guide me

Comment: What the data $91.3$ minutes of any use in the question then?

Comment: Also if I don't define $X$ as  total number of minutes than won't it cause trouble in answering the part $b$ since it talks about john doesn't scoring in first $45-min$. How will I implement this $45$ $min$ info in the $pdf$ to answer the question?

Comment: This question also has $2$ more parts...and in one of those parts the question it asks is to  find first $x$ minutes during which probability of John not scoring is $0.5$. I think the question itself suggests to use $X$ as r.v that represents number of minutes. Further your guidance will be appreciated Sir.

Comment: If you look at $(b)$ for example, $\mu$ is $45/91.3$ and what you are trying to find is $P(X=0) = \frac{(45/91.3)^0 e^{(-45/91.3)}}{0!}$

Comment: where $X$ is random variable that gives number of goals

Comment: If you use $t$ instead of $45$, you can find $t$ for which $P(X=0) = 0.5$

Comment: So in Part $a)$ the $pdf$ will remain in its general form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126215/discussion-between-math-lover-and-ameer786).